# HTML IE Set focus on Button without JavaScript

Tags: html, button, focus

is it possible to set focus on a specific button in a form, without javascript?

if no, how is it possible to do this with js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried something for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5, the tag `<button>` has the attribute `autofocus`, which sets the focus to the button when the page loads.

To set the focus to a button via javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").focus();
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.

I guess then HTML 4 does not support this?

Comment: Yeah, on HTML4 the `autofocus` attribute doesn't work, you will need to use the javascript approach